# Write back only the changed records to the xml from dataset

Tags: xml, vb.net, dataset

I have a dataset which I am loading from an xml file (using `ReadXml()` ). Now I update the changes to XML using `WriteXml()`. But I want to know is it possible to write back only the changed records to the xml
file instead of saving the whole file back to disk. If possible then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible.

An XML file is really just structured text. You can't write text into the middle of a file unless you can be absolutely sure that the new text occupies exactly the same amount of binary space as the old text. In your case, you can be pretty sure that that won't be the case, so writing to the middle of the file is simply not an option. You basically just have to overwrite the entire file to be sure that the current state of the file matches the current state of the data.

Source: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?780877-Write-back-only-the-changed-records-to-the-xml-from-dataset&highlight=